# Show site blurb also for logged-in users

Tags: feature-request, design, header, site-description

All sites in the network have a blurb at the top, telling visitors what the site is all about:

- "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required."
- "Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development. It's 100% free, no registration required."
- etc.

However, this description is not visible for logged-in users and I cannot find this text anywhere once I'm logged in.

I sign up for an SE site whenever I see a useful answer I want to upvote or just to leave a comment. The problem is that I often forget what each site is exactly for and whether or not I should mark a post as off-topic.

Having a way to enable the site topic blurb or at least adding it somewhere where it can be seen during the flagging process (perhaps only the off-topic section) would be most helpful.

Perhaps it would also suffice to just keep the banner for new users, and have them close it once ("don't show this again") after they've signed up. At the moment, after you've signed up there is no mention of what the site is about. For most of my accounts, I've never even seen the blurb.

Comment: If you really want to see it, simply browse in private/incognito mode.

Comment: Related: [Where can we find a site charter/purpose that tells us the types of question on/off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387354/289691)

Answer (score 7):

The `/tour` page gives a quick overview of the site - accessible from `help` link in the top bar.

The `/help/on-topic` page gives more details about what's on topic for the site. This is accessible from the `help/help center` via the "What topics can I ask about here?" link.

I think these pages already do what you want.

Comment: Its about quick and easy detail, not searching for a description; am I right @jmiserez ?

Comment: I agree. I often browse the network using the links on the right. If I come across a question on a site I'm unfamiliar with, my options to figure out what it's about are: Opening the menu and scrolling down to the site I'm already on, or going help -> what's on topic and parsing the rather long explanation.